# Angular UI router - abstract state with named template best practice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

i'm newbie with angular ui router and i'm trying to make a state config with
an abstract state which have the the common templates shared to the child states, and the child states which have their own templates and controller.

```
angular.module('app').config(['$stateProvider',
        function($stateProvider) {
            $stateProvider
            .state('catalog', {
              abstract:true,
              url: '/catalog',
              views: {
               "":{
                templateUrl: 'modules/catalog/views/catalog.client.view.html',
               },
               "productAdd@catalog": {
                 templateUrl: 'modules/catalog/views/catalog.product_add.client.view.html',
                 controller: 'ProductAddController'
               },
               "productList@catalog": {
                 templateUrl: 'modules/catalog/views/catalog.productList.client.view.html',
                 controller: 'ProductListController'
               }
              }
            })
            .state('catalog.base', {

            })
            .state('catalog.productDetail', {
             params: {
               productId: "no_code"
             },
             templateUrl: 'modules/catalog/views/catalog.productDetail.client.view.html',
             controller: 'ProductDetailController'
            });
        }
```

]);

To land in this module i put this simple anchor on a navigation bar:

```
<a ui-sref="catalog.base">go</a>
```

This kind of navigation works but i was wondering if there was a clearer way to write this navigation avoiding the "empty" state
"catalog.base" but maintaining the structure of an abstract state containing the common named view and the anonimous one.\

here the "catalog.client.view.html":

```
<div class="new-row">
    <div class="product-add-col">
        <div ui-view="productAdd"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="new-row">
    <div class="product-list-col">
      <div ui-view="productList"></div>
    </div>
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you just name it `catalog` instead of `catalog.base` and make it *not* abstract?

And then `catalog.productDetail` would activate `catalog`.
The docs explicitly say that we're [not](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#what-do-child-states-inherit-from-parent-states) talking about inheritance here:

> Child states DO inherit the following from parent states:
>
> - Resolved dependencies via resolve
> - Custom data properties Nothing else is inherited (no controllers, templates, url, etc).

Point is a state does not have to be abstract to have child states that activate it. This is what the docs [say](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#abstract-states):

> An abstract state can have child states but can not get activated
>   itself. An 'abstract' state is simply a state that can't be
>   transitioned to.

Comment: ok so i don't need to render the state 'catalog' abstract, but how i can share the named views with the child state? It make sense to share those views or i have to redesign the navigation?

Comment: That happens by default, child states "activate" parent states even if the parent is not abstract. Works like inheritance but it's not according to the documentation.

Comment: Ah ok now i've have understand the point of the question..thanks very much for the clarification.